# COCOA: How to create a round button. It should be clickable only in its boundary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create a round button which is only clickable in its boundaries.

**What I have done**

```
// imported QuartzCore
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

//created an IBOutlet for the button
IBOutlet NSButton* btn;

//defined the button height width (same)
#define ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT 150

//set corner radius
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT);
    btn.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT/2.0f;
}
```

//set view layer to YES

[image]

**Problem**

1. The button is clickable outside its boundaries.
2. When I am setting its position and when I am resizing the window it is getting back to its right position (the actual positon of the button is center of the window)

[image]

I have also tried to subclass `NSButton` and assign the class to the button but results are the same.

```
#import "roundBtn.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation roundBtn

#define ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT 142

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.


    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT);
    self.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT/2.0f;
}

@end
```

Comment: You'll need to subclass `NSButton`.

Comment: @trojanfoe, as it is `COCOA` we have `NSButton`. As you suggested, I have created a subclass for `NSButton` but the results are still same

Comment: You haven't shown your code (the code you show is not of a subclass).  You have not explained precisely what the issue is.  Voting to close as *Too Broad*.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have updated the question and provided all the code and please let me know if you need to something else

Comment: Rounded button in iOS, this might help you, have a look : https://github.com/balram3429/btSimpleRippleButton

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sir, as it is COCOA I will not be able to use UIButtons...

Comment: @VikasBansal: I know thats why I mentioned iOS, and might help you. Check the codes how Balram created the action only over the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reimplement the button behavior using a custom NSView and then it will respect the mouseDown events of a masksToBounds layer. NSButton doesn't work this way so the only way to tell your subclassed button that it won't be hit outside of the circle is to override the `-hitTest:` method to detect hits within the circle:

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint {
    NSPoint p = [self convertPoint:aPoint fromView:self.superview];
    CGFloat midX = NSMidX(self.bounds);
    CGFloat midY = NSMidY(self.bounds);
    if (sqrt(pow(p.x-midX, 2) + pow(p.y-midY, 2)) < self.bounds.size.width/2.0) {
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

In overriding this, you are telling the button that it will only register a hit if it is within the circle (using a little trigonometry). Returning self indicates the button was hit, returning nil indicates it was not hit.